# Updating WPF Datagrid's SelectedItem from a ViewModel and have the changes reflected back in the Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I've searched for a solution to this problem for a long time now and it's driving me insane. I just don't seem to find what the problem is and what to do in order to fix it.

On to the problem at hand: I'm working on a project in which i'm using WPF in combination with the MVVM pattern. I have a datagrid which I have bound to an ObservableCollection property in my ViewModel. I also have the SelectedItem property of the datagrid bound to a CurrentStudent property in my ViewModel.

Now, I want to be able to update, in the database, any selected student in the datagrid whenever i change his/her name, lastname, studentNumber or e-mail. I can update the student in the database, as i can access the selected student in the datagrid via the SelectedStudent property in my ViewModel. The big problem is that i want to change this property in my ViewModel directly and have the changes to the selected student reflected back into the datagrid as soon as i make the changes. But i can't, for the life of me, figure out what i am doing wrong. At first, what i need to do in order to achieve my goal seems so easy and trivial, but it just doesn't work. I can get the selected student into my ViewModel property but i just can't make the changes be visible in the datagrid unless i close the view and reload it and have the application load the students from the database and only THEN i get to see the changes in the datagrid.

Here is the code that doesn't work in my ViewModel:

```
EstudianteSeleccionado.Nombres = Nombres;
EstudianteSeleccionado.Apellidos = Apellidos;
EstudianteSeleccionado.Email = Email;
EstudianteSeleccionado.Matricula = Matricula;
bc.actualizarEstudiante(EstudianteSeleccionado);
```

This code is in charge of updating the selected student. Here is the definition of the property EstudianteSeleccionado:

```
private Estudiante _estudianteSeleccionado;
public Estudiante EstudianteSeleccionado 
{
    get
    {
        return _estudianteSeleccionado;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value != _estudianteSeleccionado)
        {
            _estudianteSeleccionado = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

As i already said, this is the property to which the datagrids SelectedItem is bound back in my view. Next is the XAML for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Estudiantes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding EstudianteSeleccionado, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Matr?cula" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Matricula, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombres" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Nombres, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apellidos" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Apellidos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

One last note: I checked to see if my collection of students get updated once i modify the SelectedStudent property from inside my ViewModel and it does change. It just doesn't seem to notify back to the datagrid that an item in its collection has changed. Here is the property that represents the students collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Estudiante> Estudiantes 
{
    get 
    {
        return _estudiantes;
    }
    set 
    {
        if (_estudiantes != value) 
        {
            _estudiantes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that there might be a problem with the bindings in the datagrid's DataGridTextColumn. Maybe they are not being notified of the changes, but I have tried almost every setting and it just doesn't get notified when the item in the collection gets modified from the ViewModel.

Comment: Are the properties in your `Estudiante` class notifying of property changes?

Comment: My Model classes do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Just the ViewModel Classes.

Comment: `Estudiante` should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or should have a ViewModel which exposes the model properties so the View, in this case the cells in the datagrid, can be notified.

Comment: .... I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on my classes and now it works... I just don't get it. My property implements INotifyPropertyChanged, it should notify the bounded SelectedItem  that it should change since the object changed. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The SelectedItem is being notified when it changes, not when the properties of the SelectedItem changes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the user nnmait i could solve my problem. My Model classes did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, just my ViewModels. Implementing this interface in my Model classes solved this.